# Playwright TLS Handshake problem with webkit on ubuntu 18

Tags: javascript, node.js, playwright

I am trying to use playwright for my project. I encountered an interesting problem. I am trying to run following code:

```
const { webkit } = require('playwright');

(async () => {
    const browser = await webkit.launch({
        headless: true
    });

    const context = await browser.newContext({
        ignoreHTTPSErrors: true
    })

    console.log("page loading")
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto('https://godaddy.com', {waitUntil: 'networkidle'});
    await browser.close();
    console.log("page loaded")
})();
```

If I run this code I am getting the following log:

```
buntu@ip-172-31-18-109:~/pwright$  node start
page loading
node:internal/process/promises:246
          triggerUncaughtException(err, true /* fromPromise */);
          ^

page.goto: Peer failed to perform TLS handshake
=========================== logs ===========================
navigating to "https://godaddy.com", waiting until "networkidle"
============================================================
Note: use DEBUG=pw:api environment variable to capture Playwright logs.
Error
    at Object.captureStackTrace (/home/ubuntu/pwright/node_modules/playwright/lib/utils/stackTrace.js:50:19)
    at Connection.sendMessageToServer (/home/ubuntu/pwright/node_modules/playwright/lib/client/connection.js:65:48)
    at Proxy.<anonymous> (/home/ubuntu/pwright/node_modules/playwright/lib/client/channelOwner.js:64:61)
    at /home/ubuntu/pwright/node_modules/playwright/lib/client/frame.js:102:65
    at Frame._wrapApiCall (/home/ubuntu/pwright/node_modules/playwright/lib/client/channelOwner.js:77:34)
    at Frame.goto (/home/ubuntu/pwright/node_modules/playwright/lib/client/frame.js:100:21)
    at /home/ubuntu/pwright/node_modules/playwright/lib/client/page.js:303:60
    at Page._attributeToPage (/home/ubuntu/pwright/node_modules/playwright/lib/client/page.js:238:20)
    at Page.goto (/home/ubuntu/pwright/node_modules/playwright/lib/client/page.js:303:21)
    at /home/ubuntu/pwright/start.js:14:16
```

**If I run this code immediately after the first error it runs without any problem**. But If I run this code after a minute I am getting the same TLS handshake error again.

How to resolve this problem?

PS: I am not getting this error with chomium but I need to use webkit.

Comment: Upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 should fix it. Seems like it was a bug in libsoup. libsoup is the library which WebKit is using to perform network requests. Firefox and Chromium are not using it.